# R Studio opens data frames unprompted when running code

Tags: r, rstudio

Since a few months ago I have a problem when using R studio: Sometimes when I run code (whole chunks or just single lines) and make changes in a data frame, R studio automatically opens the manipulated/ generated data frame, without being prompted to do so with `View(dataframe)` or similar. I cannot detect any patterns, i.e. it seems to happen randomly, independent of the manipulation or function used. Usually, it happens again whenever the same line is run again in the same session, but sometimes stops if the session is restarted.

I recently updated both R and R studio and use R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) and R studio Version 2023.03.0+386 (2023.03.0+386) on macOS 13.2.1.

Is there a way of stopping R studio from opening data frames unprompted while running a script?

Comment: Same problem here. Sometimes it's just once in a while, sometimes it's every single line of code I run. Anyone have any ideas on how to stop this? It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

If you hold down `Ctrl` and click on the name of the `data.frame` inside an R script (i.e. Source, not Console), it will automatically run `View(my.df)` where `my.df` is the name of the `data.frame`.

I suspect you are accidentally pressing `Ctrl` as you select code containing `data.frames`, or you have a sticky/faulty `Ctrl` key (or whatever the equivalent is on Mac with your assigned keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this has nothing to do with either the keyboard or how I select code.

Comment: Try this suggestion: Close R Studio and delete the .Rdata file in the working directory (suggestion from https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/113w44z/newly_created_variables_open_in_new_tab_how_to/

Comment: just started searching this again as I'm having another of many episodes of this.  Indeed I do run chunks with Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather often.  I wonder if it could be relevant, though it isn't as consistent as every time I use Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: @MikeM Why Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  Is this a key binding you customised?  Maybe try using a different key binding that doesn't involve Ctrl.  Personally, I use F5 to run code - its not used by default, and synergises with "refresh" (refresh the results of my code) as used in many other apps.

Comment: It's the standard for running all of the current chunk in RMarkdown, @Earlien.  I could have noted that.   I'm definitely a "notebook" fan.